# Change css background-Image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image array **images**  having four random images,

I want to change the **background-image** in style of css of class **contents**  using javascript.

for that i have created **buildimage** and **changeImage**  and on onclick tried to change it .

How can i achieve it?

```js
var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = images[index];
  document.getElementById('content').style.background - image = (img);
}

function changeImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  index++;
  index = index % 4; // This is for if this is the last image then goto first image I have 4 images so I've given 4 change accordingly 
  img.src = images[index];
}
```

```css
.contents {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="buildImage();">
  <div class="contents" id="content"></div>
  <button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem :

1. You don't need to create `img` tag to apply `background-image` in
   CSS Style
2. You are applying only image path

> Solution : You need to apply image path between `URL()` just like
>   normal CSS background image applies

Check below code :

```js
var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[index]+')';
}

function changeImage() {
    index++;
    if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
}
```

```css
.contents {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents" id="content"></div>
<button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>
```

Comment: second change not happening when in system run in local system Ide

Comment: @Jupiter, it is because of "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" this website, is not sending random image, while appying other images, it will work properly

Answer (score 2):

Variable/property names can't have hyphens in them (the interpreter would see that as "subtraction", but that wouldn't make sense). The corresponding property for `background-image` in the JavaScript DOM API is `backgroundImage`:

```
function buildImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = images[index];
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = (img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.getElementById('content').style.background - image = (img);
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = (img);
```

---

in js, you must change first character after `-` to upper case.
for example:

in css:  `border-style`

in js:   `borderStyle`

Comment: You're welcome @Jupiter. I'm glad that was helpful :)