# Why aren't my images being updated as expected?

Tags: javascript, html

was trying to follow a guide that seemed to me very straightforward and simple that i found here:

[Change css background-Image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510749/change-css-background-image-using-javascript)

however in my implementation it doesn't work. the image does not get displayed or changed. any hints?

EDIT: not the same as suggested duplicate. now that parenthesis after changeImage has been removed, the function gets repeated but the problem of not displaying any of the background images persists.

2ND EDIT: i also tried removing the parenthesis after buildImage, with the same result (no background images displayed)

```
<div id="pupa">

</div>

<script>


  var images = ['file:///Users/karin/PROJECTS/PORTFOLIO/pupal%20stage/img/stage12.jpg',
                'file:///Users/karin/PROJECTS/PORTFOLIO/pupal%20stage/img/stage34.jpg',
                'file:///Users/karin/PROJECTS/PORTFOLIO/pupal%20stage/img/stage56.jpg'];
  var index = 0;

  function buildImage() {
    console.log("setting image");
    document.getElementById('pupa').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
  }

  function changeImage() {
    index++;
    if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    console.log("changing image");
    document.getElementById('pupa').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
  }

  buildImage();

  setInterval(changeImage, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Comment: i tried removing parenthesis after changeImage, now that part is working :) thanks! however the images are still not displayed as background of the div (it has no background at all)

Comment: try changing `file:///Users/karin/PROJECTS/PORTFOLIO/pupal%20stage/img/stage12.jpg` to `img/stage12.jpg` (do that for each img). Paths must be relative to the `html` page or reachable absolute paths from the browser

Comment: Might indeed be an issue with local images. It should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6dg3o1fx/

Comment: firatozcevahir, this was my original solution but it did not work, that's why i changed it to the full path

Comment: Ivar, how do you mean? that the path is wrong? using the path 'img/stage12.jpg' doesn't work either

Comment: @firatozcevahir I guess that is the issue, because the code is working for me when using relative path. I guess the browser won't allow you to access files from your pc, due to security issues. And also check whether you have css set to display image, like `height, width, background-size` etc. And also note that you have set time delay to 3000 (3 seconds) which actually takes 3 seconds to set the first image, so it is also needed to set a default image by css or js.

Comment: @mponny well, do you see image load errors on console? If not, try setting some `width` `height` properties to your div's style. Because it looks like your div is not visible since it has no `height/width` properties set

Comment: @mponny it will be great if you could show the folder structure (path of html and files) and full code including css.

Comment: i don't see any image load errors. the width and height of the div are set to 100%, the background-size set to cover. i can access files fine from my browser (for instance, i can open the folder img and click on the images and that works) and have made html files locally that had no problem displaying images. also with javascript. i think the 3000 means 3000 milliseconds, that is 3 seconds, not 3 minutes. either way the first image at least should be displayed, since there is no delay for this one

Comment: @mponny Try the 3 images I used [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6dg3o1fx/) and see if those work for you. If they do, then it indeed seems not possible to use locally stored images.

Comment: folder structure: index.htm and style.css are placed in the same folder, in this there is a folder called img that contains the images. here is the css for the div:

Comment: #pupa {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: @Ivar what i see is grey rectangles with text "Image 1", "Image 2", "Image 3"

Comment: @mponny Then that's your issue. Either host those images online, or use a local webserver to serve them through it.

Comment: @Ivar i tried linking to this image of an apple instead and it doesn't work either: https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Enlarge/094/514/6000200094514.jpg

Comment: @firatozcevahir i am using mac, the path is correct

Comment: @mponny You can't always use any image on the net. There are several ways to prevent [hotlinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking), which seems the case here.

Comment: If you are using Safari, check this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari

Comment: @firatozcevahir seems like the only thing wrong was i set the div width/height to 100% instead of 100vw/vh. it's always some small mundane detail! had no idea the percentage could mess up the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work if you add your images in a folder called img in the same folder where the html page is.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #pupa
      {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background-position:center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pupa"></div>
    <script>
      var images = ['img/stage12.jpg',
                    'img/stage34.jpg',
                    'img/stage56.jpg'];
      var index = 0;
      document.getElementById('pupa').style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[index]})`;
      setInterval(function(){
        index=(++index >= images.length)?0:index;
        console.log(`changing image of index : ${index}`);
        document.getElementById('pupa').style.backgroundImage = `url(${images[index]})`;
      },3000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the same code tweaked a bit, and you don't need another function buildImage() to set image first, it works (make sure to check path of images)

Make sure to change width, height, background-size, image name, path etc according to your need.